# How to make an Attended call transfer with UCMA

Tags: ucma

I'm struggling with making a call transfer in a UMCA IVR app I've built. This is not using Lync.

Essentially, I have an established call from an outside user and as part of the IVR application, they select an option to be transferred. This transfer is to a configured outside number (ie: Our Live Operator). What I want to do is transfer the original caller to the outside number, and if a valid transfer is established, I want to terminate the original call. If the transfer isn't established, I want to send control back to the IVR application to handle this gracefully.

My problem is my EndTransferCall doesn't get hit when the transfer is established. I would have expected it to hit, set my AutoResetEvent and return a True, and then in my application I can disconnect the original call. Can somebody tell me what I'm missing here?

_call is an established AudioVideoCall. My application calls the Transfer method

```
private AutoResetEvent _waitForTransferComplete = new AutoResetEvent(false);

public override bool Transfer(string number, int retries = 3)
        {
            var success = false;
            var attempt = 0;

            CallTransferOptions transferOptions = new CallTransferOptions(CallTransferType.Attended);

            while ((attempt < retries) && (success == false))
            {
                try
                {
                    attempt++;

                    _call.BeginTransfer(number, transferOptions, EndTransferCall, null);

                    // Wait for the transfer to complete
                    _waitForTransferComplete.WaitOne();

                    success = true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //TODO: Log that the transfer failed
                    //TODO: Find out what exceptions get thrown and catch the specific ones
                }
            }

            return success;
        }

        private void EndTransferCall(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                _call.EndTransfer(ar);
            }
            catch (OperationFailureException opFailEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(opFailEx.ToString());
            }
            catch (RealTimeException realTimeEx)
            {              
                Console.WriteLine(realTimeEx.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                _waitForTransferComplete.Set();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the behavior the same if you don't use the _waitForTransferComplete object? You shouldn't need it - it should be fine that the method ends, the event will still be raised. If you're forcing synchronous behavoir in order to fit in with the rest of the application though, try it like this:

```
_call.EndTransfer(
  _call.BeginTransfer (number,transferOptions,null,null)
   );
```

I'm just wondering if the waiting like that causes a problem if running on a single thread or something...